# Switchable panel on React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick

I want to make a switchable panel on React. It consists of a small panel and a large panel, and by clicking on the small panel, you can replace it with a large panel. And, I want to include an element in the panel.　Please refer to the attached image.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQAuf.png)

This is my code

```
panel.js 
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./panel.css";

function Panel() {

  const [appState,changeState] = useState({
    activeObject: null,
    Objects : [{id: 1},{id: 2},{id: 3},{id: 4,} ]
  });

  function toggleActive(index) {
    changeState({...appState,activeObject: appState.Objects[index] })
  }

  function toggleActiveStyles(index){
    if(appState.Objects[index] === appState.activeObject) {
      return "box active";
    } else {
      return "box inactive";
    }
  } 
  return (
  <div classNameq="Panel">
    { appState.Objects.map((index) => (
      <div 
        key={index} 
        className={toggleActiveStyles(index)}
        onClick={() => {
        toggleActive(index);
      }}
      ></div>
    ))}
  </div>
  );
}
```

```
css
.Panel {
   display: flex;
   height: 100vh;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   flex-flow: row-reverse;
}

.box {
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
   margin: 10px;
   transition: transform  0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.inactive{
   background-color: #3498db;
}

.active{
   transform: translate(-22.4%,0)scale(0.33);
   background-color: #c0392b;
}
```

I found some code similar to what I want to do written in vue.js, but I can't translate it to React. I'll attach the link.
https://github.com/SimonZhangITer/DataVisualization/blob/master/src/components/dashboard/dashboard.vue

https://simonzhangiter.github.io/DataVisualization/#/dashboard

Please help me.

Comment: So... you want React but you tagged the question with Vue.js?

Comment: Either way please create a [mcve] like a codesandbox and explain what exactly isn't working in it.

Comment: @T J  Oops, I got the tags wrong. I'll try the method you answered.　Thanks!